# Bootstrap5 tooltip issue

Tags: css, node.js, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I use bootstrap 5 for my website, but when using tooltips (copied from the official documentation website): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#examples

I already searched a lot on Google and here on Stackoverflow, but all these solutions doesn't work for me so here's what i got:

I get this result:

[image: bad]

instate of this:

[image: how it need to be]

My HTML code:

```
<li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted bi-geo-alt" href="https://goo.gl/maps"
                                        target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom"
                                        title="Testing"></a></li>
```

My package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1"
},
```

And I added also these imports into my index.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' // Bootstrap CSS
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css' // Bootstrap Icons
```

Comment: You must include `popper.min.js` before `bootstrap.js` or use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` / `bootstrap.bundle.js` which contains Popper in order for tooltips to work. I recommend you use https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app

Answer (score -1):

I would like to propose a solution with the simple example from the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/

Do not forget to initialize the tooltips.

```
!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>          
                
<head>              
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
                        
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
                        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>                    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'delay': { show: 3000, hide: 0 }, 'placement': 'bottom'});
        });             
    </script>           
    <style>
    .custom-tooltip {
        --bs-tooltip-bg: gray;
    }
    </style>
</head>                 

<body>                          

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-bs-html="true" 
        data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip"   
        data-bs-title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
  Tooltip with HTML
</button>                       
                        
</body>             
</html>
```